# Kubernetes: Dynamically create configuration json files from j2 templates

Tags: json, docker, jinja2, kubernetes, openshift-origin

Is there an already built in j2 template processor in kubernetes or docker? I am doing the configuration below and wanted to plugin the values on the template.

Note that using hostPath is not an option since this is using openshift and no pv/pvc can be used.

```
containers:
    - image: some-docker-image:latest
      name: some-docker-image
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/app/conf
          name: configuration-volume
.
. Do some j2 template processing here if possible.
.

volumes:
    - name: configuration-volume
      gitRepo:
        repository: "https://gitrepo/repo/example.git
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any templating support built into Kubernetes. You can easily build a templating system on top of the yaml/json files that you pass into `kubectl -f create` though. I know some folks that are using [jsonnet](http://jsonnet.org) to accomplish this.

The discussion around adding templates is happening in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23896 if you'd like to contribute.

Comment: It's easy to use existing templating if you have control over your volume's hostpath, unfortunately, if you run via deploy remotely, then there is little control. The only option I can think of is in the entrypoint, the script/command contains some function that does the template processing. But it's a very hacky solution.

Comment: I've added a link to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23896 where the discussion around adding templates to Kubernetes is happening.

Comment: Thank you for this. Will monitor this feauture.